# How to determine performance break down with entity framework?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, azure

I am using EF5 with CodeFirst approach on an AzureSQL-Database and sometimes experiencing a strong performance break down with a rather simple query on a particular table, which contains about 3.500.000 entries.

The query is:

```
context.SortimentItems3
   .Where(si => si.CashpointId == id)
   .Select(si => new { si.Id, si.PLU, si.Hash, si.Deleted, si.Price })
   .ToList()
```

where CashpointId is a foreign key (BIGINT) to another entity. It is properly indexed and typically cuts down the result set to 100-1000 SortimentItem-entries for given CashpointId.

As you see, the query is very simple. But, there are times the query is lightning fast (<100 ms) and there are times the same query for the same CashpointId takes more than 30 Seconds. After inspecting the query in IntelliTrace I saw

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p__linq__0 = 130;

SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[PLU] AS [PLU], 
[Extent1].[Hash] AS [Hash], 
[Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price]
FROM [sort].[SortimentItems3] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CashpointId] = @p__linq__0
```

and almost believed that SQL_INVARIANT would be my culprit. But this is obviously not the case as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25697669/3632753

The database is hosted in Azure (as Standard S1 Plan with 20 DTUs) and there is not much load on it due to statistics in Azure Management Portal.

What would be your approach for identifying the source of this problem?

Thanks,
Maxim

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you ran out of database connections. Are you disposing each and every `DbContext` that you are making? What about during exceptions, do you use `using` blocks/`finally` for your disposal. Undisposed `DbContext`s will stop you from accessing the database, the 30 seconds is likely to be the GC, collecting the unused `DbContext`s.

Comment: Yes, I am disposing contexts via using (var context = new MyContext()){ ... } constructs. And this problem sometimes appears on a freshly started Instance in debugger as well. I hardly imagine there are too many MyContext instances and too many objects in memory in general at this time for GC to step in

Comment: Not sure what kind of project this is. But asp.net applications recycle if they sit idle. Could it be that the app recycled and the delay is caused by the init of the db context?

Comment: If it's not a connection problem it could be an Index problem... I think that CashpointId is indexed, is it? The index usage could be related to the statistics of CashpointId. You could at least see in wich cases the query take seconds (trace the CashpointId). If you think this is the case you can have a look to this article http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/importance-of-statistics-and-how-it-works-in-sql-server-part-1.html

Comment: Yes, CashpointId is indexed. And I do have statistics under suspiction as well. Thank you for the link. I'll investigate this.

Comment: Put in some perf logging, I honestly don't this has anything to do with SQL generation.